# Xcode 4 + OpenCL: looking for a "Hello World" example which uses kernels written in separate files

Tags: xcode, opencl

I am interested in writing OpenCL kernels in separate files because it is much more convient than writing code is a multiple line string! Apple's site have a Hello World example for OpenCL but is uses the older Xcode 3 way of writing the kernels, http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OpenCL_Hello_World_Example/Introduction/Intro.html

What I am looking for is a Hello World type example that uses the new Xcode 4 way of doing things i.e. the kernels are written in separate files and calling the kernel function seems to require less code.

**Update**

I cannot find a template project, so I have started the following project on github, which replicated the code in [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/XCodeHelloWorld/XCodeHelloWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH10-SW2),

- [Xcode 4 OpenCL Example Project](https://github.com/danieljfarrell/Xcode-4-OpenCL-Example)

Incidentally, the code initially did not run for an unknown reason and gave the following error,

> Created a dispatch queue using the GeForce GT 650M Error: Element 1
>   did not match expected output.
>          Saw 0.0000, expected 1.0000

A reboot seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

They have a 10.7+ example [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/XCodeHelloWorld/XCodeHelloWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH10-SW2):

> Creating an OpenCL program in **OS X v10.7** is easy with support built
>   into Xcode. This chapter describes step-by-step how to create an
>   OpenCL project in Xcode. If you already have a working OpenCL project,
>   you need not regenerate it, but you can find information in this
>   chapter about support for OpenCL now built into Xcode.

However, they only describe the steps, they do not provide a full project.

Comment: Thank Jean. I had actually found that already. I was asking if anybody knew where to download an OpenCL project updated from Xcode 4. Maybe there isn't one!

Comment: I made a template project which I hope will be useful for others. It follows Apple's programming guide, compiles but fails at runtime. Do you have any ideas? The code is on github, https://github.com/danieljfarrell/Xcode-4-OpenCL-Example.

Comment: The culprit is: `gcl_log_cl_fatal()` on line 37. Remove, run your program. It will run and exit without crashing. On my MBP (2.9 GHz, core i7) I see the following output: `Created a dispatch queue using the Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz
Error: Element 1 did not match expected output.
       Saw 0.0000, expected 1.0000`

Comment: The line I removed is in the `GCL Generated File`. The one in which they write `Automatically generated file, do not edit!`.

Comment: @boyfarrell I found one error: on my system `gcl_create_dispatch_queue` fails to create queues on both GPU and CPU. So the computation never runs. I can't investigate this issue right now, but you could check your projects' settings and try to figure out why the queue never gets created.

Comment: I noticed that ANY OpenCL project which used the GPU failed to compute anything (it always returned zero)! I restarted my computer, ran the original code and it worked fine. This is very odd. The output you pasted indicates that it didn't work properly, you did realise that?

Comment: @boyfarrell Yes I do. The reason is in my comment above: The `gcl_create_dispatch_queue` never gets created. So the computation don't happen. So it works fine after reboot?

Comment: Yes, the project code runs fine as is, after a reboot. I guess some state on the graphics card didn't allow the queue to be created?

Comment: Same observation. Wierd. It works after reboot. I did save my uptime before reboot: `up 53 days, 12:29, 2 users, load averages: 0,32 0,27 0,26`. Well, the issue is: if the cart doesn't allow the que to be created, you use `gcl_create_dispatch_queue` to create the queue on the CPU… which also failed. I am more thinking of an issue related to the framework. Anyway, glad it works now. I will further investigate this issue when I have more time. Looks interesting.